# Ruby: How to create nested key/value relationship

Tags: ruby, nested-loops, key-value

I am trying to create a function that outputs the key and value for all entries of that JSON as described below so I can use it to send information similar to this:

```
key = "id", value = 1
key = "mem/stat1", value = 10
key = "more_stats/extra_stats/stat7", value = 5
```

Example JSON :

```
my_json =
    {
      "id": 1,
      "system_name": "System_1",
      "mem" : {
          "stat1" : 10,
          "stat2" : 1056,
          "stat3" : 10563,
      },
     "other_stats" : {
        "stat4" : 1,
        "stat5" : 2,
        "stat6" : 3,
      }, 
      "more_stats" : {
        "name" : "jdlfjsdlfjs",
        "os" : "fjsalfjsl",
        "error_count": 3
        "extra_stats" : {
            "stat7" : 5,
            "stat8" : 6,
        },
      }
    }
```

I found an answer from this question ([need help in getting nested ruby hash hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331898/need-help-in-getting-nested-ruby-hash-hierarchy)) that was helpful but even with some alterations it isn't working how I would like it:

```
def hashkeys(json, keys = [], result = [])
      if json.is_a?(Hash)
        json.each do |key, value|
          hashkeys(value, keys + [key], result)
        end
      else
        result << keys
      end
      result.join("/")
    end
```

It returns all the keys together as one string and doesn't include any of the respective values correctly as I would like.

Unwanted output of hashkeys currently:

```
id/system_name/mem/stat1/mem/stat2/...
```

Ideally I want something that takes in `my_json`:

```
find_nested_key_value(my_json)
   some logic loop involving key and value:
      if more logic needed
         another_logic_loop_for_more_nested_info
      else
         send_info(final_key, final_value)
      end
   end
 end
```

So if `final_key = "mem/stat1"` then the `final_value = 10`, then the next iteration would be `final_key = "mem/stat2"` and `final_value = 1056` and so on

How do I achieve this? and is using a function like `hashkeys` the best way to achieve this

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your input format. Is that a text file or some kind of code sketch?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired output for the JSON above? (Removing some of the keys for brevity is fine.)

Comment: The desired output is that based on the JSON it would establish what the full "key" should be and it's specific numerical or string value e.g. `system_name` would correlate to `System_1` and `mem/stats1` would correlate to `10`. Each of these related keys and values would be used as inputs into another function which would send them elsewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening nested hash to a single hash with Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521230/flattening-nested-hash-to-a-single-hash-with-ruby-rails) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836464/how-to-flatten-a-hash-making-each-key-a-unique-value

Comment: Note that in the latest version(s) of ruby you can use the `#dig` method...

`hash.dig(*key.split('/'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive method that will create a "flattened hash", a hash without nesting and where the keys are the nested keys separated by slashes.

```
 def flatten_hash(hash, result = {}, prefix = nil)
   hash.each do |k,v|
     if v.is_a? Hash
       flatten_hash(v, result, [prefix, k].compact.join('/'))
     else
       result[[prefix, k].compact.join('/')] = v
     end
   end
   result
 end

my_hash = {'id': 1, 'system_name': 'Sysem_1', 'mem': {'stat1': 10, 'stat2': 1056, 'stat3': 10563}}

flatten_hash(my_hash)
=> {"id"=>1, "system_name"=>"Sysem_1", "mem/stat1"=>10, "mem/stat2"=>1056, "mem/stat3"=>10563}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def key_path_value(key_string, my_json)    
  value = nil
  key_array = key_string.split("/")

  return value if key_array.empty?
  return my_json[key_array.last] if key_array.length == 1

  value = my_json[key_array.first.to_sym]
  key_array = key_array.drop(1)

  key_array.each do |key|
    break unless value.is_a? Hash
    value = value[key.to_sym]
  end

  return value
end
```